# Проверка на "окно недавно потеряло фокус"

Tags: c#, время, условия

Помогите пожалуйста с временным условием.

В цикле идет проверка на наличие в фокусе ли окно, необходимо как только фокус окна потерян в течении 5 секунд цикл гонять вхолостую (пропускать условия), по истечении 5 секунд снова обычная работа цикла.

пока сделал вот так:

```
IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, "Название окна");
while (true)
{
 //если hWnd нужного окна и текущего активного не совпадают, значит фокус пропал
 if (hWnd != GetForegroundWindow()) 
   {
      MessageBox.Show("тут нужная функция");
   }
 else continue;
}
```

но это совсем не то что нужно, что то никак не могу придумать как сделать.

Comment: че за прикол? повшать листенер уже не мейнстрим?

Comment: @Merlin: окно принадлежит вашей программе или нет? Если да, Winforms или WPF? Расскажите лучше, чего вы хотите добиться на более высоком уровне.

Comment: Окно не моё. На более высоком уровне:

необходимо как только фокус окна потерян в течении 5 секунд цикл гонять вхолостую (пропускать условия), по истечении 5 секунд снова обычная работа цикла. Условие в цикле неважно какое.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Правильный запрос к гуглу - `"Hook WM_ACTIVATE или WM_SETFOCUS / WM_KILLFOCUS"`.
- Все остальное, включая, естественно `"while (1) GetForegroundWindow"` - это плохие идеи.
- Кстати говоря, возможно, что `foreground window` - [это не те дроиды, которых вы ищете.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940346/foreground-vs-active-window) Я, правда, не знаю вашу настоящую задачу.